# Zeitreihe: Übersetzung von „Seasonal-Adjustement“ und „Seasonal-Differencing“

Tags: time

Does someone know how to translate the two following technical words into German? "Seasonal-Adjustement" and "Seasonal-Differencing". For more context you might look at [Zeitreihenanalyse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitreihenanalyse).
When dealing with time series, you can adjust or remove the seasonality to study a particular effect

Desaisonalising is done by
Seasonal-Adjustment are done with dummy variable
Seasonal-Differencing are done using lag differencing

Comment: **To downvoters** the terms asked for are well established technical terms in mathematics - context helps but it should not be a prerequsite for asking here. No reason to downvote if we don't know anything about maths.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saisonbereinigung) and Oxford dictionary, the correct translation for "seasonal-adjustment" is "Saisonbereinigung".

I am not sure about "seasonal-differencing". As stated by @jarnbjo and DeepL Translator, it seems to be "saisonale Differenzierung". I do not know much about the context, but if you explain it, I could try to find a better translation.

Comment: The second term you are looking for is 'saisonale Differenzierung', but it should not have been difficult to find these translations in a dictionary.

Comment: Saisonbereinigung could mean cleaning the seasonality i think, or deseasonalising which are done by both methods. I found also Saisonal-Differenzbildung for differencing. I am looking for now for Adjustment

Comment: @Neon67: the correct German term for *seasonal adjustment* **is** *Saisonbereinigung* (*Bereinigung* is sort of cleaning by adjustment when talking in maths spheres) - we're struggling with *differencing* here.

Comment: and also what is deseasonalising then ?

Comment: Depending on context "Entsaisonalisierung" is used. You may really get better answers with giving us the context you need help with.

Comment: @jarnbjo: which dictionary would you suggest?

Comment: @Takkat There is a widespread search engine called 'Google'. Go to www.google.com and enter 'Seasonal-Differencing deutsch' in the shown input field and click on the 'search' button. You will now be shown 'saisonale Differenzierung' as a suggested translation and you can use the same search engine to confirm that this expression is used in German literature on the subject. Other alternatives would e.g. be linguee.com.

Comment: @jarnbjo Google? Come on. Google is nothing without sites like us. Same with linguee. Both are just robot scrapers, but admittedly good ones. Did you notice that this very question here is on position 1 on your Google  search? That is what we want: to be found, immediately, quickly, no deviations, no further confirmations. It only works however, if we had a solid base of good answers, filtered by experienced users who  always know better than a dictionary if an expression was valid for a given context. */self-promotion*

Comment: @Takkat I am not sure if I agree. Granted, there is not exactly much traffic here on German SE, but look at Stack Overflow with its *much* higher traffic, and I would estimate >95% of the questions to be extremely trivial or duplicates with easy-to find answers from other sources. The interesting questions are drowning in all the *'The compiler says that I am missing a semicolon in line 26. What have I done wrong?'* questions. I am not sure if that is something to eager for.

Comment: @jarnbjo: I do not find it so trivial to decide whether suggestions of translations for "seasonal-adjustment" and "seasonal-differencing" are  valid identical technical terms in a German stochastics context. They might be but there are too few resources to tell and none was a dictionary. Since we do have some mathematicians here I believe we can do much better than Google. But I might be wrong and mathematical concepts of time series are widely known and trivial to everybody else.